# Java console - Remove element from arraylist, still shows up when printing

Tags: java, arraylist, console-application

I have an arraylist which I can add to using constructors. That works perfectly fine, and they show up when printing, but when I remove them, it still shows up in the list when printing, even though when I try to remove it for a second time, it says "NullPointerException", or goes to my failsafe else if. The problem therefore have to be in the printing part, or am I thinking completely incorrectly? Is it not updating the arraylist after removing an element?

Thank you.

Instance stuff - Creating Arraylist/constructor(employeeVar = int)

```
static Employees[] employee = new Employees[employeeVar];
static List<Employees> EmployeesAL = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(employee));
```

Printing Arraylist

```
else{
    System.out.println("id: " + EmployeesAL.get(i).getEmployeeID() + "Name: " + EmployeesAL.get(i).getEmployeeName());
}
```

Removing element

```
else if (employee[idToRemove].getEmployeeID() == idToRemove && customer[idToRemove].getEmployeeName() != null){
    EmployeesAL.remove(idToRemove);
    employee[idToRemove] = null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you set it up, `EmployeesAL` and `employee` are completely unbound. A change in one is not reflected in the other.

So, when you have: `[Jane, Joe, Jack]` in your `employee`, that means at first, `EmployeesAL` is also `[Jane, Joe, Jack]`. But if you then remove an employee, the effect is that the entry in the array is nulled out, but the entry in the arraylist is removed. So, removing Joe results in `employee` being `[Jane, null, Jack]` and `EmployeesAL` being `[Jane, Jack]`. Now Jack's position in the array is index 2 (`employee[2]`) and in the arraylist it's 1: `EmployeesAL.get(1)`. Your code checks `employee[idToRemove]` and then asks `EmployeeAL` to remove that index, which, obviously, is going to fail.

Why do you have 2 data structures with the same data? Stop doing that. Pick one: Either have `Employee[] employees`, or have `List<Employee>`. You probably want only the latter:

```
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
employees.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Employee("Jane"), new Employee("Joe"), etc);
```